# Android Focus allows GPS data to upload with picture, Chrome does not

Tags: android, google-chrome, gps, exif

Picture contrasting uploads from different browsers

[image: 1]

I'm using the website https://gowomple.com to document a trip I just took. This website extracts the GPS data of the pic you upload, and place a globe at the corner of the frame that you can click to see the spot the pic was taken on google maps. The attached photo has an arrow pointing to the globe, The circle shows the missing globe.
I have a Pixel 6A.
When I use Anderid firefox focus this works fine. When I use Android Chrome it does not. If I use desktop chrome it works. Is there a security setting for Android chrome that sanitizes your picture at upload?

I uploaded a picture using Android chrome and got no globe showing where the pic was taken at. I expected to see a globe. Android Focus worked fine

Comment: It is unclear who is uploading the pictures. Further it is unclear if uploading removes gps of if displaying removes gps. Where does it go wrong?

Comment: And what is Android Focus? And what does it have to do with those all?

Comment: I upload the pics from my phone to the website of my trip. Something in the Android Chrome browser strips the GPS data (probably for provacy) whereas Focus does not. I'm wondering if someone knows a chrome setting that will allow GPS to not get stripped

Comment: Focus is a firefox browser for Android

Comment: This only happens on Android 13 devices?

Comment: `Android Focus allows GPS data to upload with picture,` Confusing message. You mean: `Android Focus uploads picture and does not strip exif gps data`.

Comment: Correct! Also I have not checked it on other Android devices with chrome

Comment: It happens only on Android 13 devices.